# Class Diagram: How to represent an array of something as an operation parameter?

Tags: enterprise-architect

In an interface method I want to have a collection of SomeType as an input parameter. How do I represent that within a Class Diagram in EA?

I tried using "SomeType[]" as parameter type, but EA doesn't seem to keep track of this: for instance when I rename the class SomeType to something else, the change doesn't propagate here.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify multiplicity for each parameter of your method.

Parameter multiplicity is not directly visible in the class diagram even if you select "Full detail" in Parameter visibility in Diagram properties. But it is in the model.

Comment: I've tried this, too. The downsides of this are that (1) I don't see the parameter type as collection directly in the class diagram and (2) generated code doesn't honor this multiplicity either...

Comment: As an alternative you can create a collectionclass for your class, but that seems like a lot of work. We just change the name of the parameter to indicate the fact that it is a collection (and we use multiplicity).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is unfortunately: you can't. EA does store the name only and not the reference to the class when you specify a parameter. There are other places where that's also the case (I currently can't recall where). So if you need to track that you need to write a smart SQL to list the used parameters.

Such a SQL could look like:

```
SELECT *  FROM t_operationparams where Type = '<Search Term>'
```